# Formatting SQL output in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby

How can I add characters and chain two db queries in the puts statement of Ruby? I'm using sqlite 3

The desired output I want is

`Sam - 32`

I imagine the code would look something like this:

`puts $db.execute(SELECT first_name FROM info) + " - " + $db.execute(SELECT age FROM info)`

I know that there is an issue with converting the string to an array. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with sqlite3, this is what gives the desired output:

```
puts $db.execute(SELECT first_name || ' - ' || age FROM info)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$db.execute("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' - ', age) as name_and_age FROM info")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear which SQL library you're using, but I suspect this should get you in the right direction:

```
$db.execute( "select * from table" ) do |row|
  p row
end
```

http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/SQLite/Database.html

Comment: Using sqlite3. Thanks for the comment. This is what helped me most, but I ended up monkey-patching it a little bit. Thank you.